# Is it Possible to pass variables through session in medium level Internet Security in case Of Internet Explorer

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have created a login  page using the logic show in the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAkKC8DKN9A but unfortunately after doing the whole code in one of my sites using the same logic and hosting it our office server  i realise that this particular code doesnt work in medium level Internet security in Internet explorer .

The problem is while  passing of variables to another page using session, i figured out that variables stored in session is never passed which is the most important thing in my code  . I dont face this issue in mozilla and google chrome .

Is there any  way of passing  variables stored in session  to work in  medium level security in intenet explorer using the same code shown in the video.

Thanks

Comment: There are so many things wrong with that tutorial. I think it would be a good idea to try to find some better tutorials

Comment: @Lex : I thoroughly understood that tutorial and i feel its pretty good , well can you recommend some good tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this stuff some more and I've been searching the web for some tutorials for login system, but I can't find one that covers everything appropriately. I think it would be better to just read up on every aspect of it individually.

For instance; most of the tutorials I've seen don't even know the difference between encrypting or hashing. The one you've used even uses `md5(md5($pw));` to make "better encryption", just thinking of production code that actually uses this makes me cringe.

So what I think you should do is think about what kind of stuff do you need for a good, safe login system. Ask questions like; "How do I store passwords safely?", "What is the best practice for redirecting a user?", "What is SQL injection and how can I prevent it?" and "What is the difference between GET and POST requests and when should I use which one?". If you try to get an answer to these questions one by one you will find much better answers. Then, with a good understanding of how this stuff works it will be easy to piece together a safe and user-friendly login system.